# How can I draw bitmap over the text in editfield?

Tags: blackberry

I would like to draw bitmap image over the text that I type in editfield.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to subclass `EditField` and then override the `paint` method. In the override, call `super.paint` before you do anything so that the component can draw the text, and then you can use the `Graphics` object provided by paint to draw a `Bitmap` over the contents of the `EditField` (`Graphics.drawBitmap`).

Comment: I follow you post, it is powerful. Thank you so much